# Select varchar column to uuidv5 in postgressql

Tags: uuid, postgresql-9.6

I have a column1 with varchar data type , I want to select column1,and converted uuidv5 value of column1   is it possible in postgres?

ex: value is 73bc7820-d739-50d9-699f-e9e1ec6aab80 
I need this to be converted to v5 using (column1,'url.com')

Comment: Just cast it if it contains a valid uuid: `column1::uuid`

Comment: Column1 value is not a uuid I need to convert it first

Comment: So what does it contain? You can't convert any arbitrary value to a UUID. Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some [sample data](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: my bad i have uuid value but convert it to v5. using uuid_generate_v5. is there way i can select uuid v5 value of existing value

Comment: No, the "version" of a UUID is determined when it's created (it's part of the algorithm to create it). But why do you care about the version? You have a valid UUID string. You can simply cast that to `uuid`

Comment: I was looking at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55938941/how-can-i-transform-a-uuid-to-a-uuid5-during-select-or-insert-queries-in-postg/55939738
creating a view it says HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
i have externion installed uuid-ossp          | 1.1     | public     | generate universally unique identifiers (UUIDs). 

create view public.new_view as SELECT uuid_generate_v5(column1,'url.com'),column1 from table limit 1;

Comment: its for business user to provide in diffrent format. i can create new view or table

Comment: The _format_ of the UUID will be exactly the same if you cast it to `uuid`